# How to split a value from database in view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table called book :

```
 public partial class Book
{
    public Book()

    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title Name")]
    [StringLength(70,MinimumLength =3)]
    public string Book_name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Edition")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int Edition { get; set; }    


    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Author Name")]
    public string Author_name { get; set; }



}
```

In this table an attribute called Author_Name .

Author_Name usually I save inside it values like :

```
Name1,Name2,Name3
```

and in my view I tried to split it's value to make a specific link to each one , but I failed to do that .. Here is my view code :

```
@model SmartBookLibrary.ViewModel.BooksDetailsVm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Book.Book_name;

    var s = Model.Book.Author_name.ToString();
    string[] Auth= s.Split(',');
}
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
                    <p itemprop="author"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> <b>Author Name :</b>
@foreach(var val in Auth){
<a style="color:#777777" href="~/Author/@Model.Book.Author_name">@Auth.ToString();</a>
}

</p><hr>         </div>                                                                              </div>
```

So when I check the result , it's not printing anything or showing any error .. how to solve that and thanks ..

Comment: Don't use code in the view like that and don't use entity models as viewmodels. Introduce a separate viewmodel that holds the properties you want to display.

Comment: Actually I'm using ViewModel only when I have a data collected from mixed or more than one table ... but in term of getting data from one table or directly , I'm using the model directly .. is that a problem or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way :

```
@{
   //var s = Model.Book.Author_name.ToString(); 
    var s = "Nazmul,khadiza,nowrin";
    string[] Auth = s.Split(',');
}
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <p itemprop="author">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> <b>Author Name :</b>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Auth.Length; i++)
        {
            <a style="color:#777777">@Auth[i];</a>
        }

        </p><hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

or if you  Calling `.ToString()` on an array will return `System.String[]`so If you want to display each value in the array try this :

```
 @foreach (string val in Auth)
            {
                <a style="color:#777777">@val;</a>
            }
```

output :
[image]